# project 2d function into 3d

Tags: plotting

Say I have a simple 2D function like $y=100-x^2$. I want to also represent it in a third dimension "z".  I will then combine this with a 3-dimensional figure (say Plot3D depiction of a pyramid) so that the vertical projection of $y=100-x^2$ "slices" the pyramid.

---

I've got this:

```
p41 = Plot3D[(1/2) ((1 - x/8) + (1 - y/17) - 
     Abs[(1 - x/8) - (1 - y/17)]), {y, 5, 17}, {x, 5, 8}, 
  BoxRatios -> 1, FaceGrids -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Opacity[0.2]}, ViewPoint -> {2, 2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 17}, {0, 10}, {0, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> Large]

p42 = Plot3D[0 x + 0 y, {y, 0, 17}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Yellow]
```

[image]
[image]

I can combine them using `Show[p41, p42]`.  I would also like to add in a vertical 3D surface in {x, y, z} space with something like:

```
p43 = Plot[10 - x^1.3/4, {x, 0, 17}]
```

[image]

Comment: $y = 100-x^2$ is not a 2D function.  Find an online plot such as you seek and we'll show you how to program it.

Comment: I've got this:  p41 = Plot3D[(1/2) ((1 - x/8) + (1 - y/17) - 
     Abs[(1 - x/8) - (1 - y/17)]), {y, 5, 17}, {x, 5, 8}, 
  BoxRatios -> 1, FaceGrids -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Opacity[0.2]}, ViewPoint -> {2, 2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 17}, {0, 10}, {0, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> Large], this: p42 = Plot3D[0 x + 0 y, {y, 0, 17}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Yellow].  I can combine them using Show[p41, p42].  I would also like to add in a vertical 3D surface in {x, y, z} space with something like:  p43 = Plot[10 - x^1.3/4, {x, 0, 17}].

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
Show[
   Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 50]}],
   ParametricPlot3D[{x, 100 - x^2, z}, {x, -12, 12}, {z, -50, 50}]
]
```